# Launch multiple X displays on boot

Tags: x11, startx

I'm running a machine with seven monitors on two GPUs.  Each monitor runs an independent full-screen application and there is no need for X-inputs (no mouse, no keyboards) or even a desktop environment.

How can I create a systemd service which:

- Creates an X display attached to a specific monitor
- Runs a fullscreen application on this X display
- Runs a VNC server on this X display (port specified)

I intend to create one of these services for each of the seven monitors.

---

Update:  I'm getting closer.  I can now run windows and VNC for each display.  I'm still having trouble getting it to run automatically, and also having troubles thinking about how I am going to split up one script into several services.

First I use `nvidia-settings` to generate an `xorg.conf` with each monitor on a seperate screen.  Then boot into a headless environment:

```
sudo mv xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo systemctl mask gdm
sudo reboot
```

I create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=0.0 cvlc video1.mp4 & 
DISPLAY=0.1 cvlc video2.mp4 &

x11vnc -display :0.0 &
x11vnc -display :0.1
```

From tty2, I run:

```
$ xinit /path/to/script
```

This will play video1 on monitor 1, and video2 on monitor2.  Then I can VNC to the two monitors using ports 5900 and 5901.

If I try to run this as a service:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=xinit /path/to/script
```

The service fails with:

```
/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

And `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` contains:

```
(WW) NVIDIA(GO): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
(WW) NVIDIA(GO): Option "metamodes" is not used
(WW) NVIDIA(GO): Failed to set the display configuration
(WW) NVIDIA(GO):  - Setting a mode on head 0 failed: Insufficient permissions
(WW) NVIDIA(GO):  - Setting a mode on head 1 failed: Insufficient permissions
(WW) NVIDIA(GO):  - Setting a mode on head 2 failed: Insufficient permissions
(WW) NVIDIA(GO):  - Setting a mode on head 3 failed: Insufficient permissions
```

---

Update2: Getting even closer.

From TTY2, I run `xinit`
From TTY3, I run `systemctl --user start disp@{0,1,2,3,4,5,6} vnc@{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}`.

Where `~/.config/systemd/user/disp@.service` is:

```
[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY:0.%i
ExecStart=cvlc /path/to/file%i.mp4
```

And where ~/.config/systemd/user/vnc@.service` is:

```
[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY:0.%i
ExecStart=x11vnc -display :0.%i
```

Now I just need to figure out how to get that user to login on startup and then run `xinit`.

Comment: Debug by looking at the X server log (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`), and **reading** the `xorg.conf` file, together with the manpages (including nvidia docs), making adjustments as necessary.

Comment: The `xorg.conf` generated is in line with [Nvidia Chapter 15](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.137/README/configmultxscreens.html) with multiple devices, and multiple screens each referencing `MonitorX`, `ScreenX` and `DeviceX`.